# div is not staying at the top of page while making position is fixed in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im making one that is fixed with page(position fixed), but it should fix in the top of the page always while scrolling 
like this site -

> http://www.simplilearn.com/project-management/pmp-certification-training

in this site drop as query form that is sticking always top while scrolling down , initially its in the middle , after reaching that position it will stick into top untill the page ends scrolling

here is my code of style

```
.right-tab {
position: fixed;
background-color: red;
 z-index:100; 
 top:0;
 left:0;
  }
```

here is my body

```
 <div >
    <h1>Sample This 
    Will go up while scrolling </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right-tab">
    <h1>Sample This Will not  go up while scrolling </h1>
    </div>
```

[image: Before scrolling the page]

[image: After scrolling the page]

Comment: Additionally in your povided example css attribut top is also defined

Answer (score 2):

> https://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/743/
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/743/embedded/result/

```
<div class="long">Long Div to enable scrolling</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="navwrap">NAV WRAP</div>
</div>

JAVA SCRIPT


function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#navwrap");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
}

$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

STYLES

```
#container {
    padding: 1000px 0 2500px;
}
#navwrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #C00;
}

.long {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #aaa);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a00, #000);
    color: white;
    height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use z-index too:

```
.right-tab {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:100;
    top:0;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr1gccfh/)

Comment: i tried but it still sticking in initial position . i want when it scrolled , it should stick in top of the page.@Siamak Ferdos

Answer (score 0):

Please use following css

```
.right-tab {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:100;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the position where you want it to be fixed

```
 .right-tab {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: red;
       top:0;
       left:0; // change the axis with your values
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for two separate DOM objects (i.e your right-tab class). Just use one element and use javascript/jQuery to make it fixed when it's time. Check for the window scroll position and the elements posiion, and when the critera is met:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if(window.pageYOffset >= $('.right-tab').position().top)
      // Add fixed styling to your .right-tab element here to make it fixed
   else 
      // Remove the fixed styling
```